# Temporarily installing R packages on Hadoop nodes for streaming jobs

Tags: r, hadoop, streaming

I have access to a Hadoop cluster that has base R (2.14.1) but no additional packages installed in every node. I've been writing base R mapper and reducer streaming scripts to get around the fact that I have no additional packages. However, I've come to a point where I need to use certain packages, rjson mainly, as part of my scripts.

I don't have admin privileges on the cluster, and the user accounts are fairly restricted. Having the cluster admins install the package on every node is not an option (for now), and the cluster has no external internet access.

I've uploaded the rjson_0.2.8.tar.gz source file to my gateway node. Is it possible to install R packages temporarily by adding `install.packages("rjson_0.2.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, lib = /tmp)` or something along those lines, such that the package is intalled when the script starts, and pass the source via the -cacheArchive parameter of the streaming job? I'd like the package to be installed in a temp location such that it dissapears when the job is complete.

Is this even possible?

I know I'll get some "use python" answers since it's for processing JSON, which is an option, but the question is for any package. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of rmr (project RHadoop). We are experimenting with a pretty radical approach to side step the installation issue. We package the whole R distribution, packages and everything in a jar, using the streaming features as you describe but with one degree of indirectness. The R distribution is loaded to a user hdfs directory, not a tmp directory. Streaming then moves it to each node. The job itself will move it to its final destination whenever it's not present already. We did so because the whole distro is not tiny and we wanted to take advantage of the caching features of streaming, plus components of R are not relocatable. So you would rebuild the jar and move it to hdfs whenever you update something or add a package. The rest is automatic and happens only when needed (hdfs->nodes->final location). I even got some coaching from the Hortonworks guys to do it right.  We have a proof of concept in the branch 0-install, but it works only for ubuntu/EC2 and apparently I managed to hard code some paths that I shouldn't have and I am making a number of other assumptions, so this is only for developers willing to chip in, but the main ingredients are all in place. Of course this is conditional to you writing your jobs with rmr, which is a separate decision, or you could just take a look at the code and reproduce the approach for your purposes. But I'd rather have this solved once and for all for everybody. The script preparing the jar is this: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/blob/0-install/rmr/pkg/tools/0-install/setup-jar and the rest of the action is in rmr:::rhstream

Comment: this sounds like an interesting approach. I'd like to learn more about it. My environment is RHEL. I actually tried installing a package from source from the gateway but I get a "can't compile" error possibly due to user restrictions. Another approach I tried is to tar.gz the installation directory of a package on another RHEL machine and submit it with job as an archive, but I haven't been able to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do as you suggest with the `-cacheArchive` argument - but note that this has been deprecated and you should be using `-archives` instead.

Another point to note, using `-archives` over `-files` will mean that your tar.gz file will be unpacked by the task tracker (rather than you having to manually unpack it).

Either way the file or unpacked files will be available in the current working directory when your code executes, and from there you'll be able to register the modules packages as per the mechanisms available in R (i've never used R, so you're on your own from here)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a temporary directory (e.g., using tempfile from **R** or **mkdtemp** from python). Make sure the name of the directory is unique, otherwise **R** will report error when multiple mappers  simutaneously install packages to a same location. This temporary directory can be used as the library location for `install.packages`. The directory is in the location defined by `mapred.child.tmp` property. Under default setup,  it will be removed after the corresponding mapper completes. You can also set mapred.child.tmp to a particular location (e.g., `-D mapred.child.tmp=/tmp/`), but Hadoop may not delete the temporary directory.